# screenfetch and neofetch shows diffirent GPU for the same system

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, kde, hardware, amdgpu

Here are the two outputs of `screenfetch` and `neofetch` for my Kubuntu 18.04 running on Toshiba Satellite L850 Laptop. They show two different GPUs. Why does it do that?

``````
screenfetch
qt.svg: link splitter-grip-focused hasn't been detected!
qt.svg: link splitter-grip-focused hasn't been detected!
                          ./+o+-       saidbakr@Satellite-L850-A700
                  yyyyy- -yyyyyy+      OS: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic
               ://+//////-yyyyyyo      Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.0.0-37-generic
           .++ .:/++++++/-.+sss/`      Uptime: 1h 3m
         .:++o:  /++++++++/:--:/-      Packages: 3447
        o:+o+:++.`..```.-/oo+++++/     Shell: bash 4.4.20
       .:+o:+o/.          `+sssoo+/    Resolution: 1440x900
  .++/+:+oo+o:`             /sssooo.   DE: KDE 5.47.0 / Plasma 5.12.9
 /+++//+:`oo+o               /::--:.   WM: KWin
 \+/+o+++`o++o               ++////.   WM Theme: Materia Manjaro Dark
  .++.o+++oo+:`             /dddhhh.   GTK Theme: Layan-dark [GTK2/3]
       .+.o+oo:.          `oddhhhh+    Icon Theme: Tela-dark
        \+.++o+o``-````.:ohdhhhhh+     Font: Noto Sans Regular
         `:o+++ `ohhhhhhhhyo++os:      CPU: Intel Core i5-2450M @ 4x 3.1GHz [53.0°C]
           .o:`.syhhhhhhh/.oo++o`      GPU: AMD TURKS (DRM 2.50.0 / 5.0.0-37-generic, LLVM 8.0.0)
               /osyyyyyyo++ooo+++/     RAM: 3031MiB / 7933MiB
                   ````` +oo+++o\:    
                          `oo++.
``````

```
neofetch
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               saidbakr@Satellite-L850-A700 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           ---------------------------- 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: Satellite L850-A700 PSKDLV-03C 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 5.0.0-37-generic 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 1 hour, 3 mins 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 3447 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: bash 4.4.20 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 1440x900 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   DE: KDE 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: KWin 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   WM Theme: Layan 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Theme: Layan [KDE], Layan-dark [GTK3 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Icons: Tela-dark [KDE], Tela-dark [G 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     Terminal: terminator 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      CPU: Intel i5-2450M (4) @ 3.100GHz 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       GPU: AMD Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Serie 
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-         Memory: 3150MiB / 7933MiB 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:` 
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not completely familiar with how neofetch and screenfetch work internally, but if you look at the Wikipedia page here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radeon_HD_7000_series

You'll note that the 716M 40 nm transistors are codenamed Turks, which are likely what your GPU uses. Basically, one command shows the GPU family name, whereas the other one uses a more specific codename pertaining to the specific GPU model.